# Unable to change the default placeholder in html for type="date"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Unable to change the default placeholder in html for type="date" as DD.MM.YYYY. Can anyone help me out in this.

Comment: The short answer: no. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/1772933 -- however, there are loads of jquery plugins out there to help

Answer (score 1):

We need to do is we need to add ***onfocus*** in input type as shown below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- PLEASE LIKE!-->
<!--code by ALOK-->

<html>
<body>
<h4>Please like answer if helpful</h4>

<!--write in placeholder what you want to show-->
<label>date:</label>
<input type='text' placeholder='Date' onfocus="(this.type='date')"></input>


</body>
</html>


</body>
</html>
```

Above code will normally show the input as ‘text’ but as we click on it type will change from ‘text’ to ‘date’.